# Vulkan. Не рисует после подключения UniformBuffer

Tags: c++, графика, vulkan

После подключение UniformBuffer программа перестала отрисовывать что-либо кроме backGround color.

```cpp
void createDescriptorSetLayout() {
    VkDescriptorSetLayoutBinding descriptorSetLayoutBinding;
    descriptorSetLayoutBinding.binding = 0;
    descriptorSetLayoutBinding.descriptorType = VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_UNIFORM_BUFFER;
    descriptorSetLayoutBinding.descriptorCount = 1;
    descriptorSetLayoutBinding.stageFlags = VK_SHADER_STAGE_VERTEX_BIT;
    descriptorSetLayoutBinding.pImmutableSamplers = 0;

    VkDescriptorSetLayoutCreateInfo descriptorSetLayoutCreateInfo;
    descriptorSetLayoutCreateInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_DESCRIPTOR_SET_LAYOUT_CREATE_INFO;
    descriptorSetLayoutCreateInfo.pNext = 0;
    descriptorSetLayoutCreateInfo.flags = 0;
    descriptorSetLayoutCreateInfo.bindingCount = 1;
    descriptorSetLayoutCreateInfo.pBindings = &descriptorSetLayoutBinding;

    auto res = vkCreateDescriptorSetLayout(device, &descriptorSetLayoutCreateInfo, 0, &descriptorSetLayout);
    assert_vulkan(res);
}

void createPipeline() {
    auto shaderCodeVert = readFile("vert.spv");
    auto shaderCodeFrag = readFile("frag.spv");

    createShaderModule(shaderCodeFrag, &shaderModuleFrag);
    createShaderModule(shaderCodeVert, &shaderModuleVert);

    VkPipelineShaderStageCreateInfo piplineShaderCreateInfoVert{};
    piplineShaderCreateInfoVert.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_SHADER_STAGE_CREATE_INFO;
    piplineShaderCreateInfoVert.pNext = 0;
    piplineShaderCreateInfoVert.flags = 0;
    piplineShaderCreateInfoVert.stage = VK_SHADER_STAGE_VERTEX_BIT;
    piplineShaderCreateInfoVert.module = shaderModuleVert;
    piplineShaderCreateInfoVert.pName = "main";
    piplineShaderCreateInfoVert.pSpecializationInfo = 0;

    VkPipelineShaderStageCreateInfo piplineShaderCreateInfoFrag{};
    piplineShaderCreateInfoFrag.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_SHADER_STAGE_CREATE_INFO;
    piplineShaderCreateInfoFrag.pNext = 0;
    piplineShaderCreateInfoFrag.flags = 0;
    piplineShaderCreateInfoFrag.stage = VK_SHADER_STAGE_FRAGMENT_BIT;
    piplineShaderCreateInfoFrag.module = shaderModuleFrag;
    piplineShaderCreateInfoFrag.pName = "main";
    piplineShaderCreateInfoFrag.pSpecializationInfo = 0;

    VkPipelineShaderStageCreateInfo shaderStages[]{ piplineShaderCreateInfoVert , piplineShaderCreateInfoFrag };

    auto vertexBindingDescription = Vertex::getBindingDescription();
    auto vertexAttributeDescrtions = Vertex::getAttributeDescription();

    VkPipelineVertexInputStateCreateInfo inputVertexCreateInfo{};
    inputVertexCreateInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_VERTEX_INPUT_STATE_CREATE_INFO;
    inputVertexCreateInfo.pNext = 0;
    inputVertexCreateInfo.flags = 0;
    inputVertexCreateInfo.vertexBindingDescriptionCount = 1;
    inputVertexCreateInfo.pVertexBindingDescriptions = &vertexBindingDescription;
    inputVertexCreateInfo.vertexAttributeDescriptionCount = vertexAttributeDescrtions.size();
    inputVertexCreateInfo.pVertexAttributeDescriptions = vertexAttributeDescrtions.data();

    VkPipelineInputAssemblyStateCreateInfo inputAssemblyCreateInfo{};
    inputAssemblyCreateInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_INPUT_ASSEMBLY_STATE_CREATE_INFO;
    inputAssemblyCreateInfo.pNext = 0;
    inputAssemblyCreateInfo.flags = 0;
    inputAssemblyCreateInfo.topology = VK_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLE_LIST;
    inputAssemblyCreateInfo.primitiveRestartEnable = VK_FALSE;

    VkViewport vkViewPort;
    vkViewPort.x = 0;
    vkViewPort.y = 0;
    vkViewPort.width = width;
    vkViewPort.height = height;
    vkViewPort.minDepth = 0;
    vkViewPort.maxDepth = 1;

    VkRect2D scissor;
    scissor.offset = { 0,0 };
    scissor.extent = { width, height };

    VkPipelineViewportStateCreateInfo viewportStateCreateInfo{};
    viewportStateCreateInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_VIEWPORT_STATE_CREATE_INFO;
    viewportStateCreateInfo.pNext = 0;
    viewportStateCreateInfo.flags = 0;
    viewportStateCreateInfo.viewportCount = 1;
    viewportStateCreateInfo.pViewports = &vkViewPort;
    viewportStateCreateInfo.scissorCount = 1;
    viewportStateCreateInfo.pScissors = &scissor;

    VkPipelineRasterizationStateCreateInfo pipelineRasterizationStateCreateInfo{};
    pipelineRasterizationStateCreateInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_RASTERIZATION_STATE_CREATE_INFO;
    pipelineRasterizationStateCreateInfo.pNext = 0;
    pipelineRasterizationStateCreateInfo.flags = 0;
    pipelineRasterizationStateCreateInfo.depthClampEnable = VK_FALSE;
    pipelineRasterizationStateCreateInfo.rasterizerDiscardEnable = VK_FALSE;
    pipelineRasterizationStateCreateInfo.polygonMode = VK_POLYGON_MODE_FILL;
    pipelineRasterizationStateCreateInfo.cullMode = VK_CULL_MODE_BACK_BIT;
    pipelineRasterizationStateCreateInfo.frontFace = VK_FRONT_FACE_COUNTER_CLOCKWISE;
    pipelineRasterizationStateCreateInfo.depthBiasEnable = VK_FALSE;
    pipelineRasterizationStateCreateInfo.depthBiasConstantFactor = 0;
    pipelineRasterizationStateCreateInfo.depthBiasClamp = 0;
    pipelineRasterizationStateCreateInfo.depthBiasSlopeFactor = 0;
    pipelineRasterizationStateCreateInfo.lineWidth = 1;

    VkPipelineMultisampleStateCreateInfo pipelineMultisampleStateCreateInfo{};
    pipelineMultisampleStateCreateInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_MULTISAMPLE_STATE_CREATE_INFO;
    pipelineMultisampleStateCreateInfo.pNext = 0;
    pipelineMultisampleStateCreateInfo.flags = 0;
    pipelineMultisampleStateCreateInfo.rasterizationSamples = VK_SAMPLE_COUNT_1_BIT;
    pipelineMultisampleStateCreateInfo.sampleShadingEnable = VK_FALSE;
    pipelineMultisampleStateCreateInfo.minSampleShading = 1.0f;
    pipelineMultisampleStateCreateInfo.pSampleMask = 0;
    pipelineMultisampleStateCreateInfo.alphaToCoverageEnable = VK_FALSE;
    pipelineMultisampleStateCreateInfo.alphaToOneEnable = VK_FALSE;

    VkPipelineColorBlendAttachmentState pipelineColorBlendAttachmentState{};
    pipelineColorBlendAttachmentState.blendEnable = VK_TRUE;
    pipelineColorBlendAttachmentState.srcColorBlendFactor = VK_BLEND_FACTOR_SRC_ALPHA;
    pipelineColorBlendAttachmentState.dstColorBlendFactor = VK_BLEND_FACTOR_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA;
    pipelineColorBlendAttachmentState.colorBlendOp = VK_BLEND_OP_ADD;
    pipelineColorBlendAttachmentState.srcAlphaBlendFactor = VK_BLEND_FACTOR_ONE;
    pipelineColorBlendAttachmentState.dstAlphaBlendFactor = VK_BLEND_FACTOR_ZERO;
    pipelineColorBlendAttachmentState.alphaBlendOp = VK_BLEND_OP_ADD;
    pipelineColorBlendAttachmentState.colorWriteMask = VK_COLOR_COMPONENT_R_BIT | VK_COLOR_COMPONENT_G_BIT | VK_COLOR_COMPONENT_B_BIT | VK_COLOR_COMPONENT_A_BIT;

    VkPipelineColorBlendStateCreateInfo colorBlendCreateInfo{};
    colorBlendCreateInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_COLOR_BLEND_STATE_CREATE_INFO;
    colorBlendCreateInfo.pNext = 0;
    colorBlendCreateInfo.flags = 0;
    colorBlendCreateInfo.logicOpEnable = VK_FALSE;
    colorBlendCreateInfo.logicOp = VK_LOGIC_OP_NO_OP;
    colorBlendCreateInfo.attachmentCount = 1;
    colorBlendCreateInfo.pAttachments = &pipelineColorBlendAttachmentState;
    colorBlendCreateInfo.blendConstants[0] = 0;
    colorBlendCreateInfo.blendConstants[1] = 0;
    colorBlendCreateInfo.blendConstants[2] = 0;
    colorBlendCreateInfo.blendConstants[3] = 0;

    VkDynamicState dynamicStates[]{
        VK_DYNAMIC_STATE_VIEWPORT,
        VK_DYNAMIC_STATE_SCISSOR
    };

    VkPipelineDynamicStateCreateInfo dynamicStateCreateInfo;
    dynamicStateCreateInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_DYNAMIC_STATE_CREATE_INFO;
    dynamicStateCreateInfo.pNext = 0;
    dynamicStateCreateInfo.flags = 0;
    dynamicStateCreateInfo.dynamicStateCount = 2;
    dynamicStateCreateInfo.pDynamicStates = dynamicStates;

    VkPipelineLayoutCreateInfo pipelineLayoutCreateInfo{};
    pipelineLayoutCreateInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_LAYOUT_CREATE_INFO;
    pipelineLayoutCreateInfo.pNext = 0;
    pipelineLayoutCreateInfo.flags = 0;
    pipelineLayoutCreateInfo.setLayoutCount = 1;
    pipelineLayoutCreateInfo.pSetLayouts = &descriptorSetLayout;
    pipelineLayoutCreateInfo.pushConstantRangeCount = 0;
    pipelineLayoutCreateInfo.pPushConstantRanges = 0;

    auto res = vkCreatePipelineLayout(device, &pipelineLayoutCreateInfo, 0, &pipelineLayout);
    assert_vulkan(res);

    VkGraphicsPipelineCreateInfo pipelineCreateInfo{};
    pipelineCreateInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_GRAPHICS_PIPELINE_CREATE_INFO;
    pipelineCreateInfo.pNext = 0;
    pipelineCreateInfo.flags = 0;
    pipelineCreateInfo.stageCount = 2;
    pipelineCreateInfo.pStages = shaderStages;
    pipelineCreateInfo.pVertexInputState = &inputVertexCreateInfo;
    pipelineCreateInfo.pInputAssemblyState = &inputAssemblyCreateInfo;
    pipelineCreateInfo.pTessellationState = 0;
    pipelineCreateInfo.pViewportState = &viewportStateCreateInfo;
    pipelineCreateInfo.pRasterizationState = &pipelineRasterizationStateCreateInfo;
    pipelineCreateInfo.pMultisampleState = &pipelineMultisampleStateCreateInfo;
    pipelineCreateInfo.pDepthStencilState = 0;
    pipelineCreateInfo.pColorBlendState = &colorBlendCreateInfo;
    pipelineCreateInfo.pDynamicState = &dynamicStateCreateInfo;
    pipelineCreateInfo.layout = pipelineLayout;
    pipelineCreateInfo.renderPass = vkRenderPass;
    pipelineCreateInfo.subpass = 0;
    pipelineCreateInfo.basePipelineHandle = VK_NULL_HANDLE;
    pipelineCreateInfo.basePipelineIndex = -1;

    res = vkCreateGraphicsPipelines(device, 0, 1, &pipelineCreateInfo, 0, &pipeline);
    assert_vulkan(res);
}

void createUniformBuffer() {
    VkDeviceSize size = sizeof(MVP);
    createBuffer(size, VK_BUFFER_USAGE_UNIFORM_BUFFER_BIT, uniformBuffer, VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_VISIBLE_BIT | VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_COHERENT_BIT, uniformBufferMemory);
}

void createDescriptorPool() {
    VkDescriptorPoolSize descriptorPoolSize;
    descriptorPoolSize.type = VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_UNIFORM_BUFFER;
    descriptorPoolSize.descriptorCount = 1;

    VkDescriptorPoolCreateInfo descriptorPoolCreateInfo;
    descriptorPoolCreateInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_DESCRIPTOR_POOL_CREATE_INFO;
    descriptorPoolCreateInfo.pNext = 0;
    descriptorPoolCreateInfo.flags = 0;
    descriptorPoolCreateInfo.maxSets = 1;
    descriptorPoolCreateInfo.poolSizeCount = 1;
    descriptorPoolCreateInfo.pPoolSizes = &descriptorPoolSize;

    auto res = vkCreateDescriptorPool(device, &descriptorPoolCreateInfo, 0, &descriptorPool);
    assert_vulkan(res);
}

void createDescriptorSet() {
    VkDescriptorSetAllocateInfo descriptorSetAllocateInfo;
    descriptorSetAllocateInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_DESCRIPTOR_SET_ALLOCATE_INFO;
    descriptorSetAllocateInfo.pNext = 0;
    descriptorSetAllocateInfo.descriptorPool = descriptorPool;
    descriptorSetAllocateInfo.descriptorSetCount = 1;
    descriptorSetAllocateInfo.pSetLayouts = &descriptorSetLayout;

    auto res = vkAllocateDescriptorSets(device, &descriptorSetAllocateInfo, &descriptorSet);
    assert_vulkan(res);

    VkDescriptorBufferInfo descriptorBufferInfo;
    descriptorBufferInfo.buffer = uniformBuffer;
    descriptorBufferInfo.offset = 0;
    descriptorBufferInfo.range = sizeof(MVP);

    VkWriteDescriptorSet descriptorWrite;
    descriptorWrite.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_WRITE_DESCRIPTOR_SET;
    descriptorWrite.pNext = 0;
    descriptorWrite.dstSet = descriptorSet;
    descriptorWrite.dstBinding = 0;
    descriptorWrite.dstArrayElement = 0;
    descriptorWrite.descriptorCount = 1;
    descriptorWrite.descriptorType = VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_UNIFORM_BUFFER;
    descriptorWrite.pImageInfo = 0;
    descriptorWrite.pBufferInfo = &descriptorBufferInfo;
    descriptorWrite.pTexelBufferView = 0;

    vkUpdateDescriptorSets(device, 1, &descriptorWrite, 0, 0);
}
```

Record commandbuffer

```cpp
VkRenderPassBeginInfo renderPassBeginInfo{};
        renderPassBeginInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_RENDER_PASS_BEGIN_INFO;
        renderPassBeginInfo.pNext = 0;
        renderPassBeginInfo.renderPass = vkRenderPass;
        renderPassBeginInfo.framebuffer = frameBuffers[i];
        renderPassBeginInfo.renderArea.offset = { 0,0 };
        renderPassBeginInfo.renderArea.extent = { width, height };
        VkClearValue clearValue = { 0,0,0,1 };
        renderPassBeginInfo.clearValueCount = 1;
        renderPassBeginInfo.pClearValues = &clearValue;

        vkCmdBeginRenderPass(commandBuffers[i], &renderPassBeginInfo, VK_SUBPASS_CONTENTS_INLINE);

        vkCmdBindPipeline(commandBuffers[i], VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_GRAPHICS, pipeline);

        VkViewport vkViewPort;
        vkViewPort.x = 0;
        vkViewPort.y = 0;
        vkViewPort.width = width;
        vkViewPort.height = height;
        vkViewPort.minDepth = 0;
        vkViewPort.maxDepth = 1;
        vkCmdSetViewport(commandBuffers[i], 0, 1, &vkViewPort);

        VkRect2D scissor;
        scissor.offset = { 0,0 };
        scissor.extent = { width, height };
        vkCmdSetScissor(commandBuffers[i], 0, 1, &scissor);

        VkDeviceSize offsets[] = { 0 };
        vkCmdBindVertexBuffers(commandBuffers[i], 0, 1, &vertexBuffer, offsets);
        vkCmdBindIndexBuffer(commandBuffers[i], indexBuffer, 0, VK_INDEX_TYPE_UINT32);
        vkCmdBindDescriptorSets(commandBuffers[i], VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_GRAPHICS, pipelineLayout, 0, 1, &descriptorSet, 0, 0);
        //vkCmdDraw(commandBuffers[i], vertices.size(), 1, 0, 0);
        vkCmdDrawIndexed(commandBuffers[i], indexes.size(), 1, 0, 0, 0);

        vkCmdEndRenderPass(commandBuffers[i]);
```

loop

```cpp
auto gameStartTime = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

void updateMVP() {
    auto frameTime = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    float timeSinceStart = (float)std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(frameTime - gameStartTime).count() / 1000.0f;

    glm::mat4 model = glm::rotate(glm::mat4(), timeSinceStart * glm::radians(30.0f), glm::vec3(0, 0, 1));
    glm::mat4 view = glm::lookAt(glm::vec3(1, 1, 1), glm::vec3(0, 0, 0), glm::vec3(0, 0, 1));
    glm::mat4 projection = glm::perspective(glm::radians(60.0f), width / (float)height, 0.01f, 10.0f);
    projection[1][1] *= -1;

    MVP = projection * view * model;

    void* data;
    vkMapMemory(device, uniformBufferMemory, 0, sizeof(MVP), 0, &data);
    memcpy(data, &MVP, sizeof(MVP));
    vkUnmapMemory(device, uniformBufferMemory);
}

void gameLoop() {
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
        glfwPollEvents();
        updateMVP();
        drawFrame();
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У меня такое ощущение, что все правильно, но я криво написал момент с UpdateMVP, так как MVP в итоге всегда 0 матрица и просто сводит к 0 все точки

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема решилась за счет изменения

```
glm::mat4 model = glm::rotate(glm::mat4(), timeSinceStart * glm::radians(30.0f), glm::vec3(0, 0, 1));
```

на

```
glm::mat4 model = glm::rotate(glm::mat4(1), timeSinceStart * glm::radians(30.0f), glm::vec3(0, 0, 1));
```

Не рисовалось реально из-за того, что model = [0,0,0,....0] и в итоге занулился весь MVP и все точки отрисовались в кучку. Возникло это из-за не совпадения версий в уроке и у меня. В уроке использовалась 0.9.8.4, где mat4() - единичная матрица, а в самой новой на сегодня - просто пустая матрица